# mapreduce job on yarn exited with exitCode: -1000 beacuse of resource changed on src filesystem

Tags: azure-storage, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, azure-hdinsight

```
    Application application_1552978163044_0016 failed 5 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1552978163044_0016_000005 exited with exitCode: -1000
```

Diagnostics:

> java.io.IOException: Resource
>   abfs://xxx@xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/hdp/apps/2.6.5.3006-29/mapreduce/mapreduce.tar.gz
>   changed on src filesystem (expected 1552949440000, was 1552978240000
>   Failing this attempt. Failing the application.

Comment: Your description is too simple. If possible, please post more details about your issue at here, which include the necessary code, the environment version or others?

Answer (score 0):

Just based on the exception information, it seems to be caused by Azure Storage could not keep the original timestamp of the copied file. I searched a workaround that recommended to change the source code of `yarn-common` to disable the code block of timestamp check when copy file to avoid the exception throws to make the MR job continous to work.

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/2064ca015d1584263aac0cc20c60b925a3aff612/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/util/FSDownload.java#L255) in the latest version of `yarn-common` which check the timestamp for copied file and throws the exception.

```
/** #L255
   * Localize files.
   * @param destination destination directory
   * @throws IOException cannot read or write file
   * @throws YarnException subcommand returned an error
   */
  private void verifyAndCopy(Path destination)
      throws IOException, YarnException {
    final Path sCopy;
    try {
      sCopy = resource.getResource().toPath();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      throw new IOException("Invalid resource", e);
    }
    FileSystem sourceFs = sCopy.getFileSystem(conf);
    FileStatus sStat = sourceFs.getFileStatus(sCopy);
    if (sStat.getModificationTime() != resource.getTimestamp()) {
      throw new IOException("Resource " + sCopy +
          " changed on src filesystem (expected " + resource.getTimestamp() +
          ", was " + sStat.getModificationTime());
    }
    if (resource.getVisibility() == LocalResourceVisibility.PUBLIC) {
      if (!isPublic(sourceFs, sCopy, sStat, statCache)) {
        throw new IOException("Resource " + sCopy +
            " is not publicly accessible and as such cannot be part of the" +
            " public cache.");
      }
    }

    downloadAndUnpack(sCopy, destination);
  }
```

Comment: very sry, i forgot this question.  It was just caused by timezone. I added the timezone    configuration in my app explicitly and sloved it. But i do not why it works for Azure datalake gen2.